# No luck finding regex pattern python

Tags: python, regex

I am having no luck getting anything from this regex search.
I have a text file that looks like this:

```
REF*0F*452574437~
REF*1L*627783972~
REF*23*526344060~
REF*6O*1024817112~
DTP*336*D8*20140623~
DTP*473*D8*20191001~
DTP*474*D8*20191031~
DTP*473*D8*20191101~
```

I want to extract the lines that begin with "REF*23*" and ending with the "~"

```
txtfile = open(i + fileName, "r")
for line in txtfile:
    line = line.rstrip()
    p = re.findall(r'^REF*23*.+~', line)
    print(p)
```

But this gives me nothing.  As much as I'd like to dig deep into regex with python I need a quick solution to this.  What i'm eventually wanting is just the digits between the last "*" and the "~" Thanks

Comment: Try escaping `\*` like `^REF\*23\*.+~`

Comment: I was successful with `^REF\*23.*~$`

Comment: @Pete's solution will work, but is less elegant because the OP wants to form a group of the digits NOT including the star after 23.

Comment: Ben, please check my answer, I think I covered all your possible requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not really need a regex if the only task is **to extract the lines that begin with "REF*23*" and ending with the "~"**:

```
results = []
with open(i + fileName, "r") as txtfile:
    for line in txtfile:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line.startswith('REF*23*') and line.endswith('~'):
            results.append(line)

print(results)
```

If you need to get the digit chunks:

```
results = []
with open(i + fileName, "r") as txtfile:
    for line in txtfile:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line.startswith('REF*23*') and line.endswith('~'):
            results.append(line[7:-1]) # Just grab the slice
```

**See [non-regex approach demo](https://rextester.com/NRRJGH15487)**.

**NOTES**

- In a regex, `*` must be escaped to match a literal asterisk
- You read line by line, `re.findall(r'^REF*23*.+~', line)` makes little sense as the `re.findall` method is used to get multiple matches while you expect one
- Your regex is not anchored on the right, you need `$` or `\Z` to match `~` at the end of the line. So, if you want to use a regex, it would look like

  `m = re.search(r'^REF\*23\*(.*)~$', line):
   if m:
      results.append(m.group(1)) # To grab just the contents between delimiters
      # or
      results.append(line) # To get the whole line`

  [**See this Python demo**](https://rextester.com/HVSS42009)
- In your case, you search for lines that start and end with fixed text, thus, no need using a regex.

**Edit as an answer to the comment**

> Another text file is a very long unbroken like with hardly any spaces. I need to find where a section begins with `REF*0F*` and ends with `~`, with the number I want in between.

You may read the file line by line and grab all occurrences of 1+ digits between `REF*0F*` and `~`:

```
results = []
with open(fileName, "r") as txtfile:
    for line in txtfile:
        res = re.findall(r'REF\*0F\*(\d+)~', line)
        if len(res):
            results.extend(res)

print(results)
```

Comment: Nothing you said is objectively wrong, but allow me to present the case FOR using a regex. Changing the `findall` to a `match` eliminates your second point. The OP wants the digits between the star and the tilde, so end-of-line anchoring is not really necessary, and appending the line is capturing too much. Group-matching in regex is more elegant than hardcoding offsets within the line or getting them from `.find`.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor.  Which method is faster? I'm guessing not regex

Comment: @BenSmith I'd suggest using string methods.

Comment: @charmoniumQ As for the `re.match`, that is true, but then I'd even go for `re.fullmatch` and throw away `^` and `$`. As for the second point, you are wrong because OP clearly stated *I want to extract the lines that begin with `REF*23*` and ending with the `~`*. Anyway, I covered the regex approach, too.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, yes I went with your recommendation using re.search and appending to a list.  In one instance and string method in another.  Best

Comment: One more issue before I close this case I was hoping you could help with @WiktorStribiżew   Another text file is a very long unbroken like with hardly any spaces.  I need to find where a section begins with _REF*0F*_ and ends with '~' , with the number I want in between.  The code that worked for _REF*23*_ doesn't work here.  How do I solve this?

Comment: @Wiktor thank you sir!  Saved me so much anguish! Lol

Answer (score 1):

`*` is a special character in regex, so you have to escape it as @The Fourth Bird points out. You are using an raw string, which means you don't have to escape chars from Python-language string parsing, but you still have to escape it for the regex engine.

```
r'^REF\*23\*.+~'
```

or

```
'^REF\\*23\\*.+~'
# '\\*' -> '\*' by Python string
# '\*' matches '*' literally by regex engine
```

will work. Having to escape things twice leads to the [Leaning Toothpick Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome). Using a raw-string means you have to escape *once*, "saving some trees" in this regard.

### Additional changes

You might also want to throw parens around `.+` to match the group, if you want to match it. Also change the `findall` to `match`, unless you expect multiple matches per line.

```
results = []
with open(i + fileName, "r") as txtfile:
    line = line.rstrip()
    p = re.match(r'^REF\*23\*(.+)~', line)
    if p:
        results.append(int(p.group(1)))
```

Consider using a regex tester such as [this one](https://regex101.com/r/tmsebS/1).

Comment: Thanks.  How can I get these outputs to within a list.  When I run this they are all separate string objects being scalar

Comment: perfect.  Thanks

Comment: One more issue before I close this case I was hoping you could help with @charmoniumQ Another text file is a very long unbroken like with hardly any spaces. I need to find where a section begins with _REF*0F*_ and ends with '~' , with the number I want in between. The code that worked for _REF*23*_ doesn't work here. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can entirely use string functions to get only the digits (though a simple regex might be more easy to understand, really):

```
raw = """
REF*0F*452574437~
REF*1L*627783972~
REF*23*526344060~
REF*6O*1024817112~
DTP*336*D8*20140623~
DTP*473*D8*20191001~
DTP*474*D8*20191031~
DTP*473*D8*20191101~
"""

result = [digits[:-1]
          for line in raw.split("\n") if line.startswith("REF*23*") and line.endswith("~")
          for splitted in [line.split("*")]
          for digits in [splitted[-1]]]
print(result)
```

This yields

```
['526344060']
```

Comment: Yeah that Is much easier.  RE is a pain